# xset: unable to open display "" error in my Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have a bash script that checks the status of caps lock and num lock and then notifies the user whenever it's changed, if I run it from the terminal everything works fine but if I initiate it from systemd, the "systemctl status command" gives me the following error:

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

here is the source code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/lib/kbled-notifier/delay.conf

echo "kbled-notifier.service: ## Starting ##" | systemd-cat -p info


#Validate the $delay parameter
case $delay in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) delay=2000 ;;
    *) ;;
esac


nofity-it () {
gdbus call --session \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.Notifications \
    --object-path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications \
    --method=org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
    '' $IDSET "$icon" "$title" "$text" \
    '[]' '{"urgency": <1>}' $delay
}

parse-id () {
    sed 's/(uint32 \([0-9]\+\),)/\1/g'
}

IDSET=0
wasoffc="true"
wasoffn="true"

while [ true ]
do

#Retrieves the current status of Caps Lock and Num Lock
capstat=$( xset -q | sed -n 's/^.*Caps Lock:\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p' )
numstat=$( xset -q | sed -n 's/^.*Num Lock:\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p' )

if [[ $capstat == "on" ]] && [ ${wasoffc} = "true" ];
then
    title="Caps Lock"
    text="ON"
    icon="/usr/share/icons/kbled-indicator/capson.png"
    IDSET=$(nofity-it | parse-id)
    wasoffc="false"
fi
if [[ ${wasoffc} == "false" ]] && [[ $capstat == "off" ]];
then
    title="Caps Lock"
    text="OFF"
    icon="/usr/share/icons/kbled-indicator/capsoff.png"
    IDSET=$(nofity-it | parse-id)
    wasoffc="true"
fi

if [[ $numstat == "on" ]] && [[ ${wasoffn} == "true" ]];
then
    title="Num Lock"
    text="ON"
    icon="/usr/share/icons/kbled-indicator/numon.png"
    IDSET=$(nofity-it | parse-id)
    wasoffn="false"
fi
if [[ $numstat == "off" ]] && [[ ${wasoffn} == "false" ]];
then
    title="Num Lock"
    text="OFF"
    icon="/usr/share/icons/kbled-indicator/numoff.png"
    IDSET=$(nofity-it | parse-id)
    wasoffn="true"
fi
sleep 0.05
done
```

this is the content of the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Notifier For Status of Caps Lock & Num Lock

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/lib/kbled-notifier/kbled-notifier-daemon
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: `xset` is Xorg tool, it interacts with X server. Environment variable `DISPLAY` indicates where X server is located (and which display to use). Systemd service knows nothing about X server. You can set `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0` and probably under some circumstances it may work.

Comment: Seems like XY problem. Why do you run script related to user interface as a system service?

Comment: where should I run the script @dimich? I guess setting `:0` may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Please define "the user".

Comment: Try to put `export DISPLAY=:0` towards the beginning of your script, to see if it works.

Comment: as an option or workaround: <br>
what about to put that notifier in autostart on login with `gnome-startup-applications`?<br>
(instead of trying to run d-bus session with systemd service)

Comment: @Amirreza There may be no graphical sessions running at all. There may be multiple graphical sessions running simultaneously. There may be non-X user sessions. As a dirty solution you can enumerate logged in users with something like `who | sed -n 's/^\(\S\+\).*(\(:[0-9]\+\))$/\1 \2/p' | while read USER_NAME DISPLAY_NO; do ... done`. Better way is to run X-related programs as a part of X session after DISPLAY is set by `xinit`, for example by your display manager.